# How to use an enumeration type, when the values are not known at first?

Tags: c, dependency-management

We have a project, that consists of a cluster of C source code, a C library and a C++ library. The C++ library is dependent only upon the C library, or at least that is what I am trying to achieve.

There is a component of the C library, called `PresetsManager`, containing:

```
PresetsManager_init(PresetItemId id);
```

The id-s are allocated manually via an `enum`. As such, the file, containing the enumeration resides inside the common source folder, because it is project-specific.

```
typedef enum {A, B, C, D, INVALID_VALUE=-1} PresetItemId;
```

This makes the C library dependent upon the project source for compilation. I tried fixing this by moving the type inside the library, and leaving the enumerated constants outside, with different name.

Library:

```
PresetsManager_init(PresetItemId id);
typedef enum {INVALID_VALUE=-1} PresetItemId;
```

Project:

```
typedef enum {A, B, C, D} PresetItemId_value;
```

So the compilation problem was solved. But now, when querying `PresetItemId`'s type via Eclipse's "Go to Definition", we *no longer* are taken to the list of constants, that is inside the project's specific source code.

How can this decoupling be achieved in a proper way?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the problem: are you trying to compile the C library only once yet have it work with multiple project-specific definitions of `PresetItemId`?

Comment: @Doval, kind of. `gcc` actually doesn't check if passed constants are members of the expected `enum`. I want to have a type `PresetItemId` inside the library for readability (instead of `int`), yet the library should be unaware of the concrete values clients are going to pass.

Comment: I get that. But are the clients going to have *different* values for each of the constants? If not, why can't the enum be part of the C library's headers?

Comment: @Doval, it appears the the logic doesn't tolerate holes in the enumeration, because resources are allocated for each enumerated value `static LargeStruct g_allocated[PI_COUNT]`.

Comment: We seem to be talking past each other. I didn't ask about holes, and it's still not clear to me whether you want to have multiple definitions of `PresetItemId`; it's therefore not clear to me why you want this decoupling. I don't even know what the role of the "cluster of C source code" is.